# What are the additional benefits of having a blockchain behind a web service?

Tags: blockchain, altcoin, value

I'm still in the process of trying to understand cryptocurrency markets, and the factors behind their monetary value.

Today, I have seen an ICO for a token called DetectorToken, which is a service that analyses markets and sends notifications to its users. From my understanding, although it seems an interesting idea, in the end, it is just another web service. The only thing I have found in the [White Paper](https://detectortoken.com/docs/DetectorToken_White_Paper.pdf) was the following:

> We intend to initiate a subscription model after the ICO thus helping investors to earn from the subscriptions made by users.

I do understand that they are trying to get their work funded, but how does such a project benefit from having a blockchain behind it, and why would it have a currency attached to it?

Answer (score 2):

It has a blockchain behind it for one reason only: buzzword compliance.